# Serialising async hasMany relationships

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, active-model-serializers

I'm fairly new to EmberJS, and I've been fiddling around for most of the evening trying to persist some hasMany and many to many relationships in a new app that I'm working on.

I'm using Ember Data with `ActiveModelAdapter` to hook it up to my rails backend which is using `ActiveModelSerializers`

I'm using the following versions of Ember and Ember Data that I'm using.

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.6.0-beta.1+canary.d0f5f254
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7+canary.d5562867
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.1.1
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.10.2
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

The basic problem I've been having is that when saving records, the association ids aren't being sent back to the server.

I took a dive into the [ActiveModelSerializer source](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/activemodel-adapter/lib/system/active_model_serializer.js#L51), and found that it skips hasMany serialization

```
var ActiveModelSerializer = RESTSerializer.extend({ // ...
  /**
    Does not serialize hasMany relationships by default.
  */
  serializeHasMany: Ember.K,
}
```

I've come up with the following rudimentary solution, which is working so far, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner solution that follows Ember convention and best practices.

```
DS.ActiveModelAdapter.reopen
  namespace: 'api/v1'

App.Store = DS.Store.extend
  adapter: '-active-model'

App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend
  serializeHasMany: (record, json, relationship) ->
    if relationship.options.async
      key = relationship.key
      data = record.get("data.#{key}")
      if data?
        json[@keyForRelationship(key, "hasMany")] = data.mapBy(Ember.get(this, "primaryKey"))
    return
```

Comment: Used your solution, works fine, I just removed relationship.options.async, which is not my case. Maybe it is time to open an issue in ember-data github?

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, the reason that the active model serializer skips has many relations is that it expects the backend to handle it. In a relational database, the values of a has many are not explicitly saved on the parent record. It is sufficient to save the foreign key in the child. When you ask for a cleaner solution - perhaps `ActiveModelSerializer` is not the best fit for your API.

Comment: You make a good point. How do you then trigger the saving of the children in this situation (using Ember and JSONAPI with AMS)?

Comment: Are you able to answer this perhaps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39506375/emberjs-2-7-has-many-configuration-for-ember-data-and-active-model-serializers